# What's the purpose of OutputMode in flatMapGroupsWithState? How/where is it used?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm exploring `KeyValueGroupedDataset.flatMapGroupsWithState` for arbitrary stateful aggregation in Spark Structured Streaming.

The signature of the `KeyValueGroupedDataset.flatMapGroupsWithState` operator is as follows:

```
flatMapGroupsWithState[S: Encoder, U: Encoder](
  outputMode: OutputMode,
  timeoutConf: GroupStateTimeout)(
  func: (K, Iterator[V], GroupState[S]) => Iterator[U]): Dataset[U]
```

What's the purpose of the `OutputMode` argument?

While reviewing the source code (of the [FlatMapGroupsWithStateExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FlatMapGroupsWithStateExec.scala#L54) that is the underlying physical operator) I could not find any place the `OutputMode` would be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, I didn't find any uses as well. I have several theories about that:

1. The mode is here to stay consistent with the signature of `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.FlatMapGroupsWithState` logical operator. If you check `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.BasicOperators` apply method, you will notice that very often the logical operator passes all its parameter to the physical operator. I'm not sure but it looks like a design guideline but it's only my supposition.
2. It can also be a legacy reason. `FlatMapGroupsWithState` evolved from `MapGroupsWithState` in order to enforce output modes semantics. It was implemented in this PR: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17197/files ([SPARK-19858](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19858)) with `MapGroupsWithState` renamed to `FlatMapGroupsWithState` and `outputMode` added as a parameter. Maybe - if my theory from previous point is wrong - it's simply here because it passed the PR and nobody wanted to complain about it because "it was already here" principle?
3. Maybe in the future an `outputMode` will be passed to the mapping function? I found that the node used to save streaming aggregations (`StateStoreSaveExec`) uses output mode to figure out the entries to persist in the state store. Maybe it will be a new feature added soon for `*withState` transformation, as stated in the comment btw:

   > - @param outputMode the output mode of `func`